# React Testing Library - Screen debug gives output different from browser

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-redux, react-testing-library

Good day for whom who read this.
I made a tic-tac-toe game 3x3 written in typescript & redux and I'm trying to write the unit test.
For the case (X for Player 1, O for Player 2).

```
[
  X,X,X
  O,O,'',
  '','',''
]
```

The screen should alert the winner as "Player One Win"
but when I called the `screen.debug()` it throws out the message "Player 2 turn" so my test failed.

```
 test('UTC1 - 0,1,2', async () => {
  const store = initStore();
  const wrapper = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>);
  const startGameBtn = wrapper.getByText("Start New Game");
  userEvent.click(startGameBtn);
  const box0 = screen.getByTestId("0");
  userEvent.click(box0);
  const box3 = screen.getByTestId("3");
  userEvent.click(box3);
  const box1 = screen.getByTestId("1");
  userEvent.click(box1);
  const box4 = screen.getByTestId("4");
  userEvent.click(box4);
  const box2 = screen.getByTestId("2");
  userEvent.click(box2);
  screen.debug();
  const winnerIsPlayerOne = screen.getByText("Player One Win");
  expect(winnerIsPlayerOne).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

but when I test in browser it's totally fine with the message show the Winner.
Here's my React code of the rendering part

```
        <div className="tic-tac-board">
            {renderRows()}
            <div className="my-3 text-center">
                {
                    isGameStarted ? (
                        <div>
                            {
                                appState.gameOver ?
                                    <div>
                                        <div className="d-flex">
                                            {appState.playerOneWin ? "Player One Win" : appState.playerTwoWin ? "Player Two Win" : ""}
                                        </div>
                                        <button onClick={() => dispatch(startNewGame())}>Restart game</button>
                                    </div>
                                    :
                                    !isPlayerOneTurn ? "Player 2 turn" : "Player 1 turn"
                            }
                        </div>) : <button onClick={() => startGame()}>Start New Game</button>
                }

            </div>
        </div>
```

I think there's a problem with the states saved in Redux store. As the variable `gameOver` by the time I called `screen.debug()` returns false.

How can I know that this variable is updated in the reducer or is there another alternative solution?
I'd be appreciated if there are any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I found a solution, as the DOM updates are asynchronous, so I had to change the method from

```
   const winnerIsPlayerOne = screen.getByText("Player One Win");
   expect(winnerIsPlayerOne).toBeInTheDocument();
```

to

```
  const winnerIsPlayerOne = await wrapper.findByText(/player 1 win/i);
  expect(winnerIsPlayerOne.innerHTML).toEqual("Player 1 Win");
```